# Deserializing xml with multiple namespaces

Tags: c#, xml

The data source I'm using always sends over data with the same parent class (Models in the xml), with xsi:type to determine the actual type of the class. This has been working fine until they started adding a namespace to the xsi:type. Now it won't deserialize no matter what I try.

Here's the XML:

```
<ModelResource xmlns:ot="http://www.example.com/otSpace">
  <Models xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance xsi:type="ot:myChildClass">
    Stuff here
  </Models>
</ModelResource>
```

The root node

```
[XmlRoot("ModelResource")]
public class XmlRoot
{
    [XmlElement("Models")]
    public List<BaseObject> Bases { get; set; }
}
```

The parent class

```
[XmlInclude(typeof(MyChildClass))]
public abstract class BaseObject
{
}
```

The child class

```
[XmlType(TypeName = "myChildClass", Namespace = "http://www.example.com/otSpace")]
public class MyChildClass : BaseObject
{
}
```

When I deserialize this XML, I wind up with the error:

{"The specified type was not recognized: name='myChildClass', namespace='http://www.example.com/otSpace', at ."}

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These classes work with your example. I've named the classes the same as the element names just to make it easier to follow:

```
public class ModelResource
{
    public Models Models { get; set; }
}

[XmlInclude(typeof(MyChildClass))]
[XmlRoot(Namespace = "")]
public abstract class Models
{
}

[XmlType("myChildClass", Namespace = "http://www.example.com/otSpace")]
public class MyChildClass : Models
{
    [XmlText]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

See [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/pEyNcn) for a working demo.

Comment: Thanks! Setting the parent namespace explicitly to "" is the missing piece. Now I have to deal with the fact that while MyChildClass belongs to that namespace, none of its properties belong to that namespace, so I need to set them all explicitly to "" as well, but that's just busywork.